# How to take cube of $\log$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

What is the right way to solve $ \displaystyle (\log_2 n)^3 $ .

I want to decompose it in plain $\log$ without exponent.

Comment: You could break it up into $\log(n) \log(n) \log(n)$ and then use the fact that $x \log(n) = \log(n^x)$ for any $x$, and iterate this twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you mean you need to *simplify* the function $$f(n) = (\log_2 n)^3$$

There really is no simplification: it is the *cube* of a function which cannot be further simplified. I.e., any way you might manipulate the function would not result in a more simplified form.

If it is part of an equation you want to solve, please include that in your post. For example, if you have an *equation* in which $(\log_2 n)^3$ appears, there may be manipulations we can do to solve for $n$. For example, suppose we have the equation
$$(\log_2 n)^3 = 8$$

Then $$(\log_2 n)^3 = 8 \iff \log_2 n = \sqrt[\large 3]{8} = 2 \iff n = 4$$

Comment: This is the sort of stuff that help posters! +1